# How To get a Webpage total return size / Bandwidth used to call a webpage

Tags: c#

I am using HttpWebRequest to call a page and HttpWebResponse to get it result ,

My Question is how can I get or calculate the total size of the return page in Byte. besides i also want to know the traffic/Bandwidth that I used to call the page.

I am able to get the content length , but the content length does not match in Firebug or other network traffic program. Thus I do not sure whether the content length is it the size of the page or not.

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes the content is compressed and then you will have a big difference between the content-length in header and actual size of the response. Plus I think that the body size (like in fildller) includes the size of the headers also.

Comment: I've noticed that you haven't cast a vote yet. Note that with your reputation, you're now able to vote on other people's questions and answers. Upvote the ones you find useful and downvote posts which are not useful or questions that don't show research effort. For more information on voting, take a look at the [upvote privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and the [downvote privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), though please keep in mind that here, we vote on the quality of content, not for a particular person or group.

Answer (score 0):

Content.Length returns only the length of HTML, after which browser requests images and other javascript stuff

1) Fiddler acts like proxy server to calculate bandwidth size, you can try to do the same
2) Another way I see is to try to do some network level calculations
Look into [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.aspx) namespace and also [How to calculate network bandwidth speed in c#](http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2008/02/06/how_to_calculate_network_bandwidth_speed_in_c_/) can help

Hope this helps

Comment: hi ArsenMkrt, is that any namespace allow me to get the total byte in the response page ?

Comment: That namespace should give you way to calc all network bandith, but honestly I never tried that before, try to look in example I sent